# Form inside a loop how to do it the Rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Hi I have a working "blog module" on my page.

From the start. My routes looks like this:

```
  root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :announcements, only: [:new,:create,:update,:edit,:destroy,:show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

My controller actions looks like this:

static_pages_controllers.rb

```
  def home
    @announcements = Announcement.page(params[:page]).order('id DESC')
  end
```

announcements_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @announcement = Announcement.new
  end

  def create
    @announcement = Announcement.new(announcement_params)
    if @announcement.save
      flash[:success] = "Post został pomyślnie dodany"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:announcement_id])
    @comment = @announcement.comments.new(comments_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Komentarz dodano"
      redirect_to root_path }
    else
      render 'staticpages#home'
    end
  end
```

Part of the home.html.erb which lists all anouncements and under each of them it adds a form to add a comment:

```
<% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
    .... some code ....
    <% if current_user && user_signed_in? %>
      <div class="create_comment" >
        <%= render partial: 'shared/create_comments_form', locals: {announcement: announcement } %>
      </div>
    <% end %>          
  ... some code ...
<% end %>
```

And _create_comment.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for announcement.comments.create, url: announcement_comments_path(announcement.id) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :author, "#{current_user.username}:" %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :author, value: current_user.username %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control content_length" %>
  <div class="char_counter">255</div>
  <%= form.submit "Dodaj!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My question is there a better way of writing this form, because It just doesn`t look rails for me when I have to specify everywhere all those parameters. Eg. when I send parameters to _create_comment I have to pass announcement object, and in form it self I have to specify the url as it looks for create_comment_path by default.

Comment: What is your model relation ?

Comment: announcement has many comments, comment belongs to announcement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted just to handle nested resources, and need a form to create such a nested resource.

Then this should work:

```
form_for( [announcement, announcement.comments.new] ) do |form|
```

Do not use `create` in the form template, as it actually saves it to the database, you end with lots of empty comments just because somebody viewed the form.

Comment: Ok it worked :) but can you explain to me `[announcement, announcement.comments.new]` ? As I understand it, first argument is the name of object for which the form is created, and second is the actual object that will be created. Since comment is nested in announcement it have to be announcement.comments.new Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cokoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem for this. This gem will create Dynamic nested forms using jQuery.

Also I have one more suggestion. Rather then using only you can use except. Because you have used all 6 routes without index.

```
root 'static_pages#home'
  resources :announcements, except: [:index] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

**Update:**

You can use like below:

Form:

```
<%= form_for :comments do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :author, "#{current_user.username}:" %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :author, value: current_user.username %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control content_length" %>
  <div class="char_counter">255</div>
  <%= form.submit "Dodaj!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

For more info: http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: expect is a good ides :), but do you think that there is a way to pass form_for a parameter so that I don`t have to pass url?